# SQL query using Decode

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I am trying to create a query that will list all students who have ever taken a course without having all the prerequisites for that course before taking the course. A prerequisite must be passed before the follow-up course is taken. The year listed in enrolled is the academic year. Within the academic year, fall comes before winter which comes before spring. So fall comes before spring due to the schools system. Below is my database as well as my tables. I am struggling with how to SELECT students who have not completed courses in the proper order. i.e. completed CID2 before completing CID1
Here is my start to this code

```
SELECT student.FirstName, student.Lastname, Student.SID FROM student
INNER JOIN enrolled ON student.SID = enrolled.StudentID
INNER JOIN prerequisite p ON enrolled.courseID = p.CID
INNER JOIN prerequisite p1 ON enrolled.courseID = p1.CID2
WHERE p1.CID1 = True AND p.CID = FALSE
```

Comment: "*Below is my database as well as my tables.*" That would be nice to see.

Comment: @PM77-1 You can't read invisible text?

Comment: @Stouny It doesn't matter how many times we refresh the page; database and tables **aren't there**.

Comment: I edited it to include the tables and the database. I don't understand why it is taking this long to update

Comment: Please also put your `RDBMS` into the tags. Also, don't use `VARCHAR` in Oracle, use `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: @Quassnoi VARCHAR has yet to cause me problems with my query

Comment: @Stouny: In Oracle, `VARCHAR` does not distinguish between `NULL` and empty string (`''`). It may or may not be a problem for you, but the standard does prescribe `VARCHAR` to do such a distinction.

Comment: @Stouny - the Oracle documentation [tells you not to use `VARCHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#sthref116). There is no advantage in sticking to it over `VARCHAR2`; apart from anything else, you'll get comments telling you this on every question you ask *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole: "the `VARCHAR` data type is scheduled to be redefined", my eye... `VARCHAR2` was introduced in Oracle 6, in 1988, and `VARCHAR` has been scheduled to be redefined since then.

Comment: @Quassnoi - yes, I imagine they have a chuckle whenever they review that wording. But that's still the argument to pretend there's a distinction, and to avoid `VARCHAR`... just in case... one day...

Comment: Duly noted for my next table! @AlexPoole

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a, d, ea.studentId,
        ea.quarter AS a_quarter, ea.year AS a_year,
        ed.quarter AS d_quarter, ed.year AS d_year
FROM    (
        SELECT  cid1 a, cid2 d
        FROM    prerequisite
        CONNECT BY
                cid2 = PRIOR cid1
        ) c
JOIN    enrolled ea
ON      ea.courseId = c.a
LEFT JOIN
        enrolled ed
ON      ed.courseId = c.d
        AND ed.studentId = ea.studentId
WHERE   ed.studentId IS NULL
        OR
        ed.year > ed.year
        OR
        (ed.year = ea.year AND DECODE(ed.quarter, 'fall', 1, 'winter', 2, 'spring', 3) > DECODE(ea.quarter, 'fall', 1, 'winter', 2, 'spring', 3))
```